# Pycharm - pygame shows only black screen

Tags: python, pycharm

Here is the code

```
import pygame

pygame.init()


screen_width = 480 
screen_height = 640 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))


background = pygame.image.load("D:/Python/Pygame_200830/Background.png")

running = True 
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False 

    #screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0)) 
    pygame.display.update() 


pygame.quit()
```

if I open this with VS code, it works well but, when I do this with Pycham. I can't see "backgound.png"

it's just only black display... and the only difference is IDE program.

I already added external function or something... only that backgound is the problem.

Could you let me know what is the reason...?

Comment: Did you do this in a virtual enviornment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the root cause of your problem is from Pycharm configurations or venv. see if you can open the python console. If you're new to pycharm, you can find the 'python console' option at the bottom of the screen.
Also here's a link that might help you. try some of the solutions there:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/au6lvd/pycharm_code_works_but_doesnt_display_output/

Comment: by the way check the image format and make sure its the same one you typed in. it might be a .jpg instead of .png